# Search Between tables in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I Have a projects table and reports table that save today report of projects,Now I Want give on project from projects table and search in reports of it and if `report->date == Now()` return Hello and else return By.
I give user projects with this code,And I checked this code,But for any report that date dose not equal with Now() return By,But I Want one more by

```
 @foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
    @foreach($project->reports as $report)
      @if($report->date == jDate::format('y/m/d'))
         <p>hello</p>
       @else 
         <p>by</p>
     @endif
   @endforeach
 @endforch
```

Comment: Normally if you've made the relationship should be `$project->reports` that return the reports of the project.

Comment: please check again my question

Comment: Sorry but your question isn't clear enough... what you mean by _But I Want one more by_ ?!

Comment: @pedram6195  
بله در واقع میخوام بین ریپورت های هر پروژه یه سرچ انجام بشه و ا گه تاریخ امروز پیدا شد سلام اگه نه خدافظ چاپ بشه

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@php 
   $res = 'bye';
@endphp

 @foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
    @foreach($project->reports as $report)
      @if($report->date == jDate::format('y/m/d'))
         @php $res = 'hello'; @endphp
     @endif
   @endforeach
 @endforch

@if($res == 'hello')
    //anything you want (file, div,...)
@else
   //anything you want (file, div,...)
@endif
```